# SSAS 2008 Partitions

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas, ssas-2008

I have a fairly big SSAS cube. The measures are partitioned to contain 12 months of data. I have around 10 partitions for each measure. The problem is that every month after a new set of data is added, the data from exactly 12 month before 'disappears' from the cube. For example adding Jan 2017 data, makes Jan 2016 data disappear from the view (accessed from Excel) even though the data is in the database. 
After another round of cube processing, this sets itself right. Any explanation to this phenomenon? I can guess that probably the cube is realigning the partitions with an extra month added. How to solve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: How is the processing occurring? Is it done manually in the SSMS GUI? Is it through an XMLA script run by an Analysis Services DDL Task in SSIS? What kind of processing is occurring when you you add the new partition - Process Full, Process Data, Process Add...? Partition process only, cube process or database process? What happens "another round of cube processing"? Is it the same job or a different job? 

You say "the measures are partitioned to contain 12 months of data" but then you say "the data from exactly 12 month before 'disappears' from the cube. What SHOULD happen?

Comment: The cube is processed manually in SSMS GUI. It is Full cube processing.

Comment: The cube is processed manually in SSMS GUI. It is Full cube processing. For example, when I add Feb 2017 data, Feb 2016 data disappears in the application(MS EXCEL) - there is a hole. Data before Feb 2016 is all intact and is visible in the application. What should happen is that addition of new month data shouldn't make any data 'disappear'.  The cube partitions should realign and shouldn't cause a temporary glitch. Processing the cube again in the same way sets everything alright.

Comment: You're right - data shouldn't disappear especially if you are doing full cube processing. Can you confirm whether the problem is solely in Excel? In other words, in SSMS, can you browse the cube and view the data beforehand?

Comment: To resolve this problem, you will need to set up a dev/test environment in which you try to duplicate the problem. I'm afraid after-the-fact diagnosis is going to be impossible, as you'll have to repro the problem to test a fix. When SSAS does a full cube process, it simply empties out each partition and reloads the data in the partition according to the table-binding or query-binding defined for that partition. The only way for something to disappear is a) the binding definition doesn't return data or b) you delete the partition. You use Profiler to watch what happens during processing.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, stacia. Is binding definition the partition condition? In this case the partition condition is- 0 to 11 months, 12 to 23 months etc..I will have to learn how to use profiler then.

Comment: @SKa, can you post examples of conditions for partition split of one measure group.

Comment: What are your partition names?   Are you re-naming the old partitions (2016) when you add the new ones (2017)?

Comment: @Ferdipux <code>select *
from fact_table
where datediff(month,period + '01',
(select max (period) from fact_table) +'01')
between 0 and 11</code> for next parition it is 'between 12 and 23' and so on.

Comment: @TabAlleman Partition names are 'Sales Fact 1' and so on. No, I am not renaming the partitions. The partition condition should take of realigning automatically ideally.

Comment: @SKa, `period` from your query have datetime data type? Or - it is a string with YYYYMM value?

Comment: @Ferdipux In database, that column is char(6). Yes the values are of YYYYMM format in the column.